# MySql query doesn't order records, when using union

Tags: mysql, union

I have 3 tables in my MySQL database.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fullname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `softs` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `plans` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SoftId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Explain` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `Rating` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Done` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `NowIs` datetime NOT NULL,
  `DoneTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `note` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `SoftId` (`SoftId`),
  KEY `userid` (`userid`),
  CONSTRAINT `plans_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`SoftId`) REFERENCES `softs` (`Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `plans_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want first to retrieve undone records and order them by 'rating' column in ascending order, followed by already done plans, ordered by 'DoneTime' column in descending order.
Therefore I wrote the query below.

```
(SELECT a.id, b.title, a.`Explain`, a.Done, a.DoneTime, a.note, c.fullname, a.rating 
    FROM plans as a 
    inner join softs as b ON b.Id = a.SoftId 
    inner join users as c ON c.id = a.userid 
    where(a.done = 0) order by a.Rating asc)
union
(SELECT a.id, b.title, a.`Explain`, a.Done, a.DoneTime, a.note, c.fullname, a.rating 
    FROM plans as a 
    inner join softs as b ON b.Id = a.SoftId 
    inner join users as c ON c.id = a.userid 
    where(a.done = 1) 
    order by a.Donetime desc) ;
```

When I ran them separately, each works fine, but with "union" records not ordered.

How I can achieve this task with one query?

Comment: Just add a flag to the SELECTs and then conditionally order by that flag.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan  I don't understand 'flags'. Can you provide simple?

Comment: I'm not sure why you tagged me in that comment? I simply removed the 'jquery' tag from the question as it's not relevant to your problem with SQL because it's a client-side JS framework.

Comment: i.e. a.id AS id, and order by id

Comment: I accidentally made that. I meant 'query'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't even see the need for a union query here, just add the appropriate `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT a.id, b.title, a.`Explain`, a.Done, a.DoneTime, a.note, c.fullname, a.rating 
FROM plans AS a 
INNER JOIN softs AS b ON b.Id = a.SoftId 
INNER JOIN users AS c ON c.id = a.userid 
ORDER BY
    a.done,    -- undone records first, done second
    CASE WHEN a.done = 0 THEN a.rating ELSE -1*UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.DoneTime) END;
```

The `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY` clause merits some explanation.  In the case of undone records, the second level sort is ascending using the rating.  In the case of *done* records, we sort by the negative number of seconds in the done time.  This will sort later done times before earlier ones (i.e. is "descending" by `DoneTime`).